# PIN on lock screen not accepting touch input. Cannot switch on

Tags: lock-screens, fastboot, bootloader, touchscreen

### **PHONE / OS**

Asus Max Pro M1 6GB variant running android oreo (8.1.0)

---

### **THE PROBLEM**

My phone after reboot is not accepting touch input at PIN lock screen. Now, I cannot switch it on.

---

### **A PREVIOUS PROBLEM**

It usually stops responding to touch randomly at any point which I used to resolve by :

Locking screen -> waiting for 30 - 40 seconds -> relocking screen. If the former did not work sometimes, I would reboot it 2 or 3 times as in the 1st, 2nd reboot the problem persisted and would go away by 3rd or 4th reboot. It's completely random as to how many reboots would it take for the touch input problem to go away.

---

### **WHAT I TRIED**

I tried to unlock the bootloader from fastboot to flash a TWRP image intending to backup my data. But unfortunately, some problem occurs saying Write to device failed / Too many links / Unknown error / Command failed, etc, etc. I have a Ryzen 3 processor, and I do know the usb 3.0 problem associated with it. I also tried changing usb cable.

---

### **WHAT I WANT**

I want to access my phone without losing data/installed apps.

---

In search of some community expertise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: to unlock screen connect pc mouse or keyboard to phone. do not unlock bootloader you will lose all data

Comment: @alecxs. Thanks, it didn't occur to me. I unlocked my phone but now I'm only able to operate it through OTG with wired mouse and keyboard. The touch still does not work. I also rebooted in safe mode, the touch doesn't work there as well.